# OpenIddict 4 WebProviders does not configure external authentication schemes

Tags: asp.net-core, openiddict, .net-7.0

I am just wondering if anyone has some experience with this. I am trying out OpenIddict 4.0.0 to put together a real-life solution with the new Identity UI and razor pages approach. However when I register an external auth provider using the suggested unified [OpenIddict.Client.WebIntegration package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/OpenIddict.Client.WebIntegration), I cannot see the providers on the default login page external section.

I also tried to use the **openiddict-core sandbox** [aspnet.core server app](https://github.com/openiddict/openiddict-core/tree/dev/sandbox) but that as well does not show the configured GitHub external login option.

I could explicitly create links for the providers, however I do not see that as a convenient solution. The default code segment that calls `SignInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemesAsync()` does not seem to collect the external providers registered using

```
options.UseWebProviders().UseGitHub() ...
```

What am I missing here? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: to improve interoperability, a native authentication scheme forwarding mechanism was added to the OpenIddict client in 4.7.0: OpenIddict providers are now automatically returned by `SignInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemesAsync()` and listed by the default UI.

See https://github.com/openiddict/openiddict-core/releases/tag/4.7.0 for more information.

---

It's a deliberate design choice, explained in [this post comparing the aspnet-contrib providers with the OpenIddict providers](https://github.com/aspnet-contrib/AspNet.Security.OAuth.Providers/issues/694#issue-1280661329):

> The aspnet-contrib providers use an authentication scheme per
> provider, which means you can do `[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "Facebook")]` to trigger an authentication dance. In contrast, the
> OpenIddict client uses a single authentication scheme and requires
> setting the issuer as an `AuthenticationProperties` item if multiple
> providers are registered.
>
> For the same reason, the providers registered via the OpenIddict
> client are not listed by Identity's
> `SignInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemesAsync()` and so don't
> appear in the "external providers" list returned by the default
> Identity UI. In practice, many users will prefer customizing this part
> to be more user-friendly, for instance by using localized provider
> names or logos, which is not something you can natively do with
> `SignInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemesAsync()` anyway.

Comment: It makes total sense now, thanks for the link, I missed that part.